# Finding the numbers on cards

Tags: elementary-number-theory, game-theory

[image]

This question is a bit confusing. I decided to start by showing that all cards don't contain the same number.

Lets say I pick a subset of $10$ cards then they have $10-19$

$10+11+12+13+..+18+19=145$ which is not divisible by $100$

but to be divisible by $100$, each card has to end in $0$ that leads to each card being $10,20,30,...80,90$ but that doesn't guarantee divisibility with the subsets.

If each card is $10$ and i take a subset containing $14$ cards, then it still wont be divisible by $100$

Any ideas on this problem?

Comment: try it with 2 cards numbered either 1 or 2, sums not divisible by 3.

Comment: if you get that, try 3 cards numbered from 1 to 3, sums not divisible by 4

Comment: You "decided to start by showing" the negation of what you're being asked to show??

Comment: @WillJagy, are you looking at $3$ and $4$ because they are factors of $100$?

Comment: 3 and 4 are small, and 3 does not divide 100. Doing the easiest cases of some type of problem, in detail, may lead you to a method yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumptions are impossible to satisfy: The sum of the *empty* subset of the cards is $0$ which *is* divisible by $100$.

The claim is therefore vacuously true. Q.E.D.

(It would have been more involved if the assumption said "... any *nonempty* subset of cards ...")

Comment: What do you mean by vacuously true?

Comment: @sharonnicole116: A claim with an assumption that is always false is true. For example, "let $n$ be an integer such that $2n$ is odd. Then the moon is made of green cheese" is vacuously true.

Comment: so in this case, the assumption is the sum of the empty subset of cards is $0$?

Comment: No, the assumption is "that the sum of the numbers on any subset of cards (including the set of _all_ cards) is not divisible by 100". This assumption is always false, _because_ the sum of the empty set of numbers is 0.

Comment: I'm sure, that this task is about nonempty sets, but also I agree, it's not precise.